# C# WPF - Add to a list in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, list, append, addition

I am a beginner in C# and WPF. I am creating a PIN system where you have digits 0-9. The user clicks a button for instance 1, and it will add 1 to a list. Being a beginner to this programming language and structure. How would I go about doing so, this is what I have so far and nothing seems to work at the moment.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class MyVariables
    {
        public static List<int> pinNumbers = new List<int>();
    }

    private void PIN_0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyVariables.pinNumbers.Add(0);
        MessageBox.Show("List = " + MyVariables.pinNumbers);
    }

    private void PIN_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyVariables.pinNumbers.Add(1);
    }
}
```

There are simply buttons, you click one and it should add to the list "pinNumbers" but it doesn't seem to be adding. Thank you, any help with be appreciated!

Some XAML

```
<Grid>
   <Button x:Name="PIN_0" Content="0" Click="PIN_0_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: *"it doesn't seem to be adding"* -- what do you mean by that? If you have those event handlers set up correctly, the code should indeed be adding to the list. How are you checking whether they've been added?

Comment: I have tried using "MessageBox.Show("List = " + MyVariables.pinNumbers) and using a foreach loop "foreach (object o in MyVariables.pinNumbers) Console.WriteLine (o);"

Comment: You'll need to include a [mcve] showing some XAML and the code you are using to display the contents of the list. The part you have right now looks okay. Also include the output you are getting from your `MessageBox` and/or `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses, I've managed to fix it. Within the XAML, only Pin_0 had a click event whereas all the other buttons didn't. Thank you for helping, I made a simple mistake and it's now working!! Thank you so much Herohtar!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to start the class in a variable and remove the static declaration

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private _myVariables { get; set; }
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      _myVariables = new MyVariables()
   }

   public class MyVariables
   {
      public List<int> pinNumbers = new List<int>();
   }

   private void PIN_0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      _myVariables.pinNumbers.Add(0);
      MessageBox.Show("List = " + _myVariables.pinNumbers);
   }

   private void PIN_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      _myVariables.pinNumbers.Add(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post and your time. I made a simple mistake and i've fixed it now. Thank you